# Spring Jdbc 4 transaction management

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm new to Spring (even to version 4.0.3 that I am currently using). In some code I have to extend, `JdbcTemplate` is uniquely used, an instance is shared among objects to keep all the sql statements under the same transaction. I'd like to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate so I get one by using

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npJT = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(givenJdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
```

Sadly `npJT` and `givenJdbcTemplate` look not to share the same transaction. This is an issue for me, how can I overcome this problem and keep all the sql instruction I'll do by using `npJT` in the same transaction as `givenJdbcTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the other [constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#NamedParameterJdbcTemplate-org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations-) which can take a JdbcTemplate as a parmeter and pass your JdbcTemplate to it.

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npJT = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(givenJdbcTemplate);
```

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention I'm using ver. 4.0.3 (I'll update my question), NamedParameterJdbcTemplate hasn't that constructor yet. Btw, could be the mean to upgrade to a not so far version, your answer is still valid! So you tried that succesfully... Good to know!

Comment: @MistakesMaker I'm a little confused, v 4.0.3.RELEASE and some older versions (I checked back to 3.0.1.RELEASE) have this constructor.

Comment: I'm confused too, you're right. Obviously I missed that constructor.. Thanks again!